# Right Click Jquery Menu don't work after a function rewrite the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm developing a simple example of Right Click Menu using Jquery. I'm using JQuery ContextMenu. So I have a simple table and the jsp code generete the cells in this way:

```
<div  id="catS" class="pure-u-1-3"> 
<h4 class="l-box">Categorie</h4> 

<table  class="pure-table pure-table-horizontal l-box" id="catAssociate">
<tbody>
<%ObjectifyService.register(Categoria.class); 
List<Key<Categoria>> lCategorie=s.getCategorie();
if(lCategorie!=null){
for(Key<Categoria> k : lCategorie){
Categoria c= ofy().load().now(k);
if(c!=null)
    %><tr id="<%out.println(c.getId());%>" ><td id="    <%out.println(c.getId());%>"   onclick="getSottocategorieDaC(this); getDispenseDaC(this)"><%out.println(c.getNome());%></td></tr> <%
}
}else{
%><tr><td>Nessuna categoria associata</td></tr><%
}
%>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

So in an other table i can add elements on the datastore and via the ajax post i update the "catAsscoiate" table. these are my function:

This add the item on the datastore and redraw my table.

```
function AddAction(t, a) {
$.ajax({
    url : 'studenteServlet?action=aggiungiC&ids='+$.urlParam('id')+'&idc='+t.id,
    type : "POST",
    async : false,
    success : function(data) {          
        console.log(data);
        $('#catAssociate tbody > tr').remove();
        var html = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    html += '<tr id='+data[i].id +'><td id='+data[i].id +' onclick="getSottocategorieDaC(this); getDispenseDaC(this)">' + data[i].nome + '</td></tr>';
        $('#catAssociate').append(html);
    }
}); 
 }
```

Before the add action the context menu works on catAssociate, after no. this is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#catAssociate tbody tr').contextMenu('myMenu2', {
    bindings: {
        'open': function(t) { DeleteAction(t, "Open"); },
    }
    ...
```

Can anyone explain me why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you replace all the html using $('#catAssociate').append(html); you effectively remove / lose all the event bindings that where attached to the old content that you just zapped.

so just reapply them after you rebuild the DOM in your success function:

```
$('#catAssociate').append(html);

$('#catAssociate tbody tr').contextMenu('myMenu2', {
    bindings: {
    'open': function(t) { DeleteAction(t, "Open"); },
}
```